# Filtered running sum view in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, view, sum, window-functions

I have an append-only `Operation` table with the following columns:

- `Id`, INTEGER, primary key, auto-incremented
- `LotId`, INTEGER, foreign key, auto-incremented
- `Amount`, INTEGER

Whenever there is a new row inserted in this table I need the balance to be reflected, so I created a `Ledger` view with:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS "Ledger" ("OperationId", "Balance") 
AS SELECT "Id", SUM("Amount") OVER (ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
FROM "Operation";
```

What I need is further filtering of the running sum by `LotId`, that is the sum should only include those rows from `Operation` where the `LotId` matches.

Example

```
Operation                  Ledger

Id | LotId |Amount         OperationId | LotId | Balance
---+-------+------         ------------+-------+--------
1  | 1     | 10            1           | 1     | 10
2  | 2     | 5             2           | 2     | 5
3  | 1     | -7            3           | 1     | 3
```

Comment: @wp78de: There seems to be a syntax error with "Exists"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `PARTITION BY` clause to get the sums by `LotId`:

```
CREATE VIEW IF NOT EXISTS Ledger AS 
SELECT Id AS OperationId, 
       LotId,
       SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY LotId ORDER BY Id) AS Balance
FROM Operation;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9y_N1r9h).